# Cannot see all results in Jmeter results tree and report

Tags: jmeter, report

I'm facing a weird situation with Jmeter 5.4.1

When running a suite, in my results tree all I can see are the results from first 7 (of 30) tests, and in the report, 20 of 30 tests.
All calls are simple and have just a status code and body response assert, and nothing more.

Anyone aware about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's "weird", it's ["by design"](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean).

By [default JMeter stores/shows 500 last results](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.properties#L1187) in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

If you want to remove this limitation you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up. Then you will be able to see all the results (given they will fit into memory)

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)